# Transferring data from a Text area to a Listbox

Tags: html

I am trying to take data that is placed into a text area and have it added to a Selectbox. I've spent several days searching online and I can find a lot of ways to do it the opposite way. Here is the HTML for the form I'm using.

```
    Keyword: <input type="text" id="enterkey">
    <button type="button" id="addkey" value="Add">Add</button>
    <div>
    <select multiple id="selectkey">
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="removekey">Remove</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're trying to add a new option to the list of select options? A select statement uses `<option value=1>Option One</option>` for each option between the select opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function(){

    $("#addkey").bind("click",function(){

        $("<option>").html($("#enterkey").val()).appendTo("#selectkey");

    });

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/CRbSw/1/